# Splitting text to columns without delimiter

Tags: google-sheets, split, delimiter

I have recently imported data into google sheets and wanted to split the text from a column into a new column. The imported data included first and last name however it combined into a single string.

EX: JohnDoe

This was the case for every name. Is there a way to split the first name and last name when you do not have a delimiter like a space or comma? The only distinction between the two is capitalization for both names. If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1; "([A-Z])"; " $1"); " ")
```

[image]

[image]